# CSS div element gets cramped up when I move the position of the anchor tag in it from inside the div to outside the div

Tags: html, css

I have a div element displayed as a card on my page which has an anchor tag inside it. Right now the anchor tag is around some text inside the div, but I would like to have the anchor tag outside the div so that the user can click anywhere in the div. However, when I move the anchor tag from inside the div to outside it, it messes up the whole div.

The code is -
Before -

```
            <div class='row second-page'>
                <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
                    <a href=''>
                    <h1>- About -</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
                    <a href=''>
                    <h1>- Projects -</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
                    <a href=''>
                    <h1>- Résumé -</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

After -

```
            <div class='row second-page'>
                <a href=''>
                <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
                    
                    <h1>- About -</h1>
                    
                </div>
                </a>
                <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
                    <a href=''>
                    <h1>- Projects -</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
                    <a href=''>
                    <h1>- Résumé -</h1>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The results are -
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMv41.png)
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsG8h.png)

Comment: Can you provide your CSS code to get more accurate answers?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `div` tag to the `a` tag instead of wrapping it so like this

before

```
<div class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <a href=''>
        <h1>- About -</h1>
    </a>
</div>
```

after

```
<a href='' class='col-xl-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 with-padding'>
    <h1>- About -</h1>
</a>
```

what you describe happens because a `a` element already has some styling properties on it witch breaks your style